# Program Resizing

Tags: windows, windows-10

I set the resolution on a program I was using too high, and the buttons to change it are off screen, along with the bar to drag the program around. Is there a way to re-scale the program, so it is playable again.

Comment: Select the program and push the `Windows Key` + `Up Arrow Key` to make it fullscreen.  (Of which you should be able to see the buttons.)

Comment: The idea suggested by the amusingly-named @CheesusCrust is simple and effective, but it won't work for windows that can't be maximized. For those, you can press `Alt`+`Space` to open the title bar context menu, then `M` to select **Move**. Then press any arrow key once and then move the mouse. Don't ask me why you need to do the arrow thing; I haven't got a clue.